# JPA Unique Renaming Unique Index

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I'm creating an entity called `Person`, basically there is a column Integer sin, with the annotation `@Column(name="per_sin", nullable=true, unique=true")`  The problem in the persistence xml file I ended up setting the hibernate to create, so it will create all the tables in the database.  The problem is that it adds a constraint as `UK_jkdfjalkfa`, but I wanted to rename the constraint to `UK_per_sin`, but I tried putting it as an annotation as `@UniqueConstraint(name="UK_per_sin")`, but when it persists it still keeps on adding the constraint with random generated value.

Answer (score 3):

For me, it's possible renaming the Unique Key constraint including an option into the `@Table` JPA tag:

```
@Table(name="tableName", 
uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(name = "UK_per_sin", columnNames= { "per_sin" } ))
```

And also not including the `unique` option into the `@Column` tag:

```
@Column(name="per_sin", nullable=true)
```